# Condition on the point cloud matrix making the points "generic" in the uniform sense

Tags: matrix-analysis, orthogonal-matrices, sampling, data-analysis, generic-points

For a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$, what condition can I impose on $X$ to make the collection of its columns generic in the sense that they look like the result of uniformly sampling a convex region in $\mathbb{R}^d$? Ideas or relevant papers are welcome and appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, the question is on uniformly sampling a convex region, right?

Comment: No, the question is on "what conditions I can impose on X" to make its columns look like uniform point cloud on a convex region.

Comment: Why make it look like the original if you can get the original?

Comment: You want something like a likelihood measure, that given $X$ will tell you how "likely" it is to come from a uniform sampling on a convex? As it is, it is unclear what you are asking. Any distribution of points may come from such a sampling, although possibly with a low likelihood.

Comment: Sorry for the confusions. I will restate the problem again.

Comment: Possibly related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/9854/91764 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/164043/91764 and https://mathoverflow.net/q/243687/91764